# Does SimpleInjector's WebAPIRequest lifetime include Message Handlers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I'm new to SimpleInjector and working through examples using it with WebAPI.   I used the `SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi.WebHost.QuickStart` nu-get package, then registered a simple type for my tests, like so:

```
container.RegisterWebApiRequest<SimplePOCO>();
```

From inside an ApiController method,  I am able to request an instance.  So far, so good.  I wanted to expand my test to earlier in pipeline, specifically a Message Handler.  So I created a simple DelegatingHandler like :

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                           HttpRequestMessage request,
                                           CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> response;

    var container =  SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer.container;
    var rc = container.GetInstance<SimplePOCO>();
    response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    response.ContinueWith((responseMsg) =>  {   });

    return response;
}
```

Calling `GetInstance<SimplePOCO>()` errors with the following message:

> The registered delegate for type SimplePOCO threw an exception. The
>   SimplePOCO is registered as 'Web API Request' lifestyle, but the
>   instance is requested outside the context of a Web API Request.

Am I doing something wrong?  Are Message Handlers outside the lifetime of a WebAPI request?  This seems odd, considering how integral they are.  If message handlers are outside the lifetime is there a longer lifetime that encompasses the message handlers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are Message Handlers outside the lifetime of a WebAPI request?

Well, as a matter of fact, they are. Unless you trigger the creation of the `IDependencyScope` explicitly, the `IDependencyScope` gets created (by calling `request.GetDependencyScope()`) inside the `DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create` method.

To make sure your code runs within a dependency scope, all you have to do is call `request.GetDependencyScope()` explicitly inside your handler:

```cs
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

    // trigger the creation of the scope.
    request.GetDependencyScope();

    Task<HttpResponseMessage> response;

    var container =  SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer.container;
    var rc = container.GetInstance<SimplePOCO>();
    response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    response.ContinueWith((responseMsg) =>  {   });

    return response;
}
```

Comment: "saving the world one software decoupling at a time."  Thanks for not taking me to task on the static reference to the container I snuck into my example :-)

Comment: @EBarr: It crossed my mind to say something about that, but I had the feeling you heard that argument before :-)

Comment: It crosses my mind every day...I work in 2 million lines of extreme coupling daily.  That was just quick shorthand while working through examples.

Comment: Maybe add this to the last post of https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/472187 as I was wondering what was going wrong :)