# Why does a Web API TypeFormatter not run in the same Call Context as the request of the request?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api

When handling a request, Web API allows the complete operation to run in a [single Context to flow with the asynchronous code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) we write in Web API. Somehow however, when creating custom a MediaTypeFormatter, Web API doesn't use the same context when executing a type formatter.

**My question is: Why is that and how can we circumvent this?**

Take a look at the following code:

```cs
public static class CallContextHelper
{
    private static readonly string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public static void Append(string text) {
        var appendedText = (string)CallContext.LogicalGetData(key) + " -> " + text;
        CallContext.LogicalSetData(key, appendedText);
        Debug.WriteLine(appendedText);
    }
}

public sealed class TestDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { }

    IDependencyScope IDependencyResolver.BeginScope() {
        CallContextHelper.Append("IDependencyResolver.BeginScope");
        return this;
    }

    object IDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType) => null;

    IEnumerable<object> IDependencyScope.GetServices(Type serviceType) =>
        Enumerable.Empty<object>();
}

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public ValuesController() {
        CallContextHelper.Append("ValuesController.ctor");
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        CallContextHelper.Append("ValuesController.Get");
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

With the following custom media type formatter:

```cs
public class MyCustomTypeFormatter : XmlMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public MyCustomTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.mywebapplication+json"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type) => false;
    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type) => true;

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream ws, 
        HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext tc)
    {
        CallContextHelper.Append("WriteToStreamAsync (begin)");

        return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, ws, content, tc)
            .ContinueWith(continuation =>
        {
            CallContextHelper.Append("WriteToStreamAsync (continu)");
        });
    }
}
```

Bootstrapper:

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new TestDependencyResolver();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new MyCustomTypeFormatter());
```

If we run the application and call the ValueController, we see the following output:

```
-> IDependencyResolver.BeginScope
-> IDependencyResolver.BeginScope -> ValuesController.ctor
-> IDependencyResolver.BeginScope -> ValuesController.ctor -> ValuesController.Get
-> WriteToStreamAsync (begin)
-> WriteToStreamAsync (begin) -> WriteToStreamAsync (continuewith)
```

In other words, what you see is that the call to `IDependencyResolver.BeginScope`, the call to the constructor of the `ValuesConstructor` and the `ValuesController.Get` method operate in the same logical call context, but the calls to the TypeFormatter operate in their own call context.

What I'm trying to do is allow everything to run in a single scope, to allow reusing the same unit of work instance throughout the request. There's no `HttpRequestMessage` passed into the TypeFormatter, so there seems no other way to get this running in a single context.

Comment: Does it not seem somewhat suspicious to you that the TypeFormatter needs access to the unit of work? Does that not seem like a *formatter* is doing things it ought not to?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I agree, that is suspicious :-). However, I'm trying to find out what's going on here in Web API and since there seems to be nothing on the internet about this, I'm hoping this question and its answers will help other developers understand what's going on.

Comment: @Steven, could you check what `SynchronizationContext.Current` is everywhere you access `CallContext`?

Comment: @Noseratio: Everywhere but in the "WriteToStreamAsync (continuewith)" the `SynchronizationContext.Current` property contains an instance of the `System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext`. In the "WriteToStreamAsync (continuewith)" delegate, `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns null.

Comment: @Noseratio: Do note that even before the ContinueWith, inside the `WriteToStreamAsync` the logical call context doesn't flow from the request to the TypeFormatter.