# Castle windsor with owin and Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, castle-windsor

i have problem with owin configuration in typical asp.net project using Identity and castle windsor.
The thing is i really like how identity and owin are managing all the user-stuff like sending cookie to loging user and so on but it requires the following code:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(OwinStartUp.Startup))]
namespace OwinStartUp
{
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.CreatePerOwinContext(DbOwinHelper.CreateDbContext);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(DbOwinHelper.CreateUserManager);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(DbOwinHelper.CreateSignInManager);                       

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,

            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, MyIdentityUser, Guid>(
         validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
         regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
         getUserIdCallback: (user) => Guid.Parse(user.GetUserId()))
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

so in e.g. controller i have to write this:

```
var signInManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

instead of this (which i preffer)

```
var signinmanager = container.Resolve<ISignInManager<IMyIdentityUser>>();
```

or at least

```
 var signinmanager = container.Resolve<ApplicationSignInManager>();
```

How can i integrate windsor with owin pipeline? Or, in very least, how to use CookieAuthentication with my custom ApplicationSignInManager without owin (and without rewriting whole cookie authentication by my own)?

I have seen a lot of articles with castle windsor as owin dependecy resolver but it was mostly about self hosting owin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after almost a year i found answer here: [WebApi + Simple Injector + OWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521558/webapi-simple-injector-owin)

there is posted this post: https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/539965
and then it leads here: [Does SimpleInjector's WebAPIRequest lifetime include Message Handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311361/does-simpleinjectors-webapirequest-lifetime-include-message-handlers)

i think all 3 of this  questions/answers combined are satisfying me.